# How to make io.read() return a string?

Tags: lua, computercraft

I am trying to learn how to program Computercraft Mining Turtles and I want to write a program that prompts the user for the side length dimensions for a cube which is then built. I use io.read() to get the user to input the side lengths and if he wants the cube to be solid or hollow via Y/N inputs. However when I check the answer to that last question I get a error that I have a table and need a string. 
Error code: Cube:17: bad argument: string expected, got table

Here's my code

```
--"Cube constructor"
--"Powered by UglySoft"

function get_dimensions()
  --"prompts for cube dimensions and Solid"

  print("Please enter the Cube dimensions.\n")

  io.write("Cube side length ")
  side_length = tonumber(io.read())

  io.write("Solid Cube? (Y/N) ")
  solid = io.read()


  solid = string:lower()

  return side_length, solid
end

function build_solid(side_length)
    print("Building solid Cube with side length ", side_length)
end

function build_hollow(side_length)
    print("Building hollow Cube with side length ", side_length)
end


function main()
    --"main part of the program"
    term.clear()
    print("Welcome to Cube Builder")
    print("powered by UglySoft \n")


    get_dimensions()

    if solid == "y" then
        build_solid()
    else
        build_hollow()
    end

end


main()
```

I am very new to lua and I am not even sure if I should use io.read() in this situation. Any help is greatly appreciated and feel free to ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `string:lower()` which de-sugars to `string.lower(string)` which tries to operate on the `string` table. That's not going to work.

You want `solid:lower()` or `string.lower(solid)`.

Comment: Also he needs to either remove side_length from parameter list in build_solid() and build_hollow() which hides the global one, or pass it in when calling either function.  Apparently, OP needs a better understanding of general programming concepts.

Answer (score 0):

In ComputerCraft you should generally use a built-in function

```
read()
```

Instead of`io.read` since `io.read` is made for reading files instead of user input.

Instead of `io.write` you can also use `write` or `print`.